# Excel 2016 freezes after every modified cell

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, freeze, microsoft-office-2016

I run Windows 10 and Office 2016. I have a network document that I frequently access. It recently started freezing after every cell I modify. It freezes for anywhere from 10 to 30 seconds, and then starts again normally. The file is 1.97 MB in size.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the conditional formatting of that section. I deleted the conditional formatting and then recreated it. After doing that the workbook stopped freezing.

Comment: Yeah, had a similar problem where the excel file size started ballooning and excel got very slow, especially on undo. Deleting all conditional formatting and recreating it helped.